# Get dependency list through Gerrit REST API

Tags: rest, gerrit

Using the Gerrit SSH `query` command it's possible to get a list of dependencies for a specific change:

```
ssh -p $port $host gerrit query --current-patch-set --format JSON --dependencies \(change:$changeid AND branch:$branch\)
```

The resulting JSON output will have a `dependsOn` and `neededBy` properties.

Are these properties possible to retrieve using the REST API of Gerrit?

I'm asking because at the moment I can use the REST API, but not SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to retrieve the dependency information using the [Get Related Changes](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#get-related-changes) endpoint.

Comment: It gives me the "relation chain", but for my test-review it doesn't contain the `dependsOn` or `neededBy` as reported by `gerrit query`.

Comment: As described in the Gerrit documentation: "Related changes are changes that either depend on, or are dependencies of the revision"